# get text from About dialog

Tags: swt, rcp, jface

I set the 'About' dialog in plugin.xml.
and want to put text to About dlg or, get at runtime.

How can I do this??

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for that. If you are happy with internal methods, then use ProductProperties.getAboutText()